# rewrite for loop as filter() javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, filter

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
var selectEnabledGenerators = function(generators) {
    //List of generator indexes to show
    var list = generators;
    var allGenerators = $(".generatorContainer");
    //Hide all generators
    allGenerators.hide();
    //maybe use filter here?
    for (var i = 0, max = list.length; i < max; i++) {
        $(".generatorContainer[data-generator=" + list[i] + "]").show();
    }
};
```

Is there any way to rewrite the `for` loop using `filter()`?
I know that I can use a `for each` loop but I want to do this by using filter.

Comment: do you need to return the filtered list? or just iterate to run the `.show()` method?

Comment: just iterate to run the ```show()``` method

Comment: @hackerrdave just iterate to run the ```show()``` method

Comment: no need/point to use `filter` if not returning anything - `for` loop or `Array.prototype.forEach()` will do the trick

Comment: Why down voting guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `filter` here. Since you're not returning anything `forEach` would be the more appropriate function.

Something along the lines of this should do:

```
list.forEach(item => $(".generatorContainer[data-generator=" + item + "]").show());
```

or

```
list.forEach(function(item){
    $(".generatorContainer[data-generator=" + item + "]").show();
});
```

if you don't like/can't use lambdas

---

**Can I use filter anyway**

Yes. But there's really **no** reason to. If I saw you using filter in this way I would reject your code review.

The use case of filter is to quickly pare down a list of items by passing in a predicate function (a function that answers "does this stay in"). This function's type for an `Array<T>` would be `T => boolean`. This filter function will execute the predicate function's code block on every item and then check the return value of that predicate function. If that return value is truthy, it will mark that object that was passed into the predicate function and then return all the objects that resulted in truthy values as a new array. `forEach` will also execute a function on each parameter, just without doing the extra work of returning a value and managing a new list.

If you do not make use of the returned result from filter, it is nonsensical to use filter. Not only is it useless, it will confuse people reading your code in the future who are trying to understand why you use filter here.

Ultimately the code is the same:

```
list.filter(item => $(".generatorContainer[data-generator=" + item + "]").show());
```

The `.show()` is treated as a side effect (which filter functions really **should not have**).

Comment: Thanks for the answer .I know about the forEach but I want to use filter().Is that possible?

Comment: I mean no disrespect, it's possible, but it's a bit dumb. I'll add more to my answer.

Comment: Why is it dumb?

Comment: I added some explanation in the answer. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: hello.I was reviewing some of my old questions and I just saw your answer.I would like to know what are the side effects that you are talking about in your last paragraph(and why filter functions should not have).

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.filter()` like this:

```
allGenerators.filter(function () {
    return list.indexOf(+$(this).attr('data-generator')) > -1
}).show();
```

Simplified demo:

```js
$('div').hide().filter(function (i) {
  return [1,3].indexOf(+$(this).attr('data-generator')) > -1
}).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-generator=1>test1</div>
<div data-generator=2>test2</div>
<div data-generator=3>test3</div>
<div data-generator=4>test4</div>
```

Comment: This is what I originally had tried but for some reason it is not working

Comment: If your list has numeric values, make sure to convert the attribute value to numeric also, with the unitary `+`. See modified answer.